# How do I export and link to a dll using Qt Creator on Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I have got a few Qt projects building on my Mac and I am currently trying to get the same code to build on Windows. In among these projects there is one dll (call it LibraryA) that exports a class (call it ClassA) that is linked to by a second dll (call it LibraryB).

I have the following code that defines the dll export code to be used based on the compiler being used.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER

    #if defined(LIBRARY_A)
        #define LIBRARY_A_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define LIBRARY_A_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif

#else

    #define LIBRARY_A_EXPORT

#endif
```

I then incorporate this into my class definitions.

```
class LIBRARY_A_EXPORT ClassA
```

However, on Windows I get unresolved symbol __declspec(dllimport) in the LibraryB.

What have I done wrong?

**EDIT** I created a couple of standalone projects to try and get this working (called LibraryA and LibraryB again). LibraryA successfully builds and in the LibraryB project I used the "Add Library" dialog, selecting External Library. This gives me the following .pro file entries which is still not working

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-LibraryA-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug/release/ -lLibraryA
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-LibraryA-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug/debug/ -lLibraryA

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../build-LibraryA-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug/debug
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../build-LibraryA-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug/debug
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a few possible scenarios:

1. LibraryA.dll is missing (not built). Probably not the case.
2. LibraryB is not able to find LibraryA. Make sure you have the proper library path in LibraryB 'pro' file: `LIBS += -L$$PWD/Path_To_LibraryA_Dll/ -lLibraryA`
3. LibraryA project doesn't have `LIBRARY_A` macro defined, and the `LIBRARY_A_EXPORT` doesn't get defined as `__declspec(dllexport)`, in which case, LibraryA won't export anything for external usage. Make sure you have the define in LibraryA 'pro' file: `DEFINES += LIBRARY_A`

Comment: I am unsure if that answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can confirm that the library is built and I actually decided to create simple LibraryA and LibraryB projects to test with. See the edit to my question for the generated .pro file entries. Unfortunately I am still getting the "unresolved symbol" error.

Comment: The `LibraryB` test project that you created should first of all fail to compile because it cannot find **librarya.h**. `$$PWD/../build-LibraryA-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug/debug` is the path of LibraryA.dll, so I suppose your include path should be something like: `INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../LibraryA`. 'Add Library' dialog fills the include path with the dll path automatically.

Comment: Afterwards, delete the whole content of `build-LibraryB-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug/debug ` in order to do a clean build of LibraryB. If you do clean from inside QtCreator, it doesn't delete anything (the generated makefiles are still the same till you do 'Run qmake'  and the dll, obj and pdb files will never get deleted)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good Qt wiki on that: [How to create a library with Qt and use it in an application](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application). Mind using `Q_DECL_EXPORT` and `Q_DECL_IMPORT` in the declarations depending on the project, whether it consumes or provides the dynamic library.