# How to correctly link your own library to your project in Qt on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qmake

In my QtCreator C++ project I'm using subdirs template and have several subprojects including lib-project. In app-project I'm trying this:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L../Library/release -lLibrary
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L../Library/debug -lLibrary
else:unix: LIBS += -L../Library -lLibrary
```

On Linux it works well, but on Windows library compiles (there're .dll and .a files), linker links it (if I change the path to wrong, like -L../Library/debugg I have an error - can't find -lLibrary), but then I have "undefined reference to [my_classes]". INCLUDEPATH and DEPENDPATH are also correct (because it works on Linux):

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/.. $$PWD/../Library
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/.. $$PWD/../Library
```

Also tried this:

```
LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../Library/release -lLibrary
```

Same result, so what should I do?

Comment: Your first three lines look fine except they are missing the PWD variable as part of the file path which seems to break it on Windows. Try changing the beginning of all your paths to -L$$PWD/../Library ($PWD prints the working directory as part of the path which is the folder containing the .pro file).

Comment: Thank you, but I've already tried LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../Library/release -lLibrary and the log shows that the resolved path is correct

Comment: Make sure you *export* the class. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34663527/how-do-i-export-and-link-to-a-dll-using-qt-creator-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34663527/how-do-i-export-and-link-to-a-dll-using-qt-creator-on-windows).

Comment: Thank you, It seems to have reduced the number of errors, when I'd used Q_DECL_EXPORT and Q_DECL_IMPORT for one class. But I have a lot, it's stupid to do this for every class, why it works on Linux without this?

Comment: `it's stupid to do this for every class, why it works on Linux without this?` Although it seems too late to comment on this issue, but anyway: it works like this, simply because *nixes and Windows treat this situation differently. Under Linux all "public" symbols are also automatically made visible ("exported') inside the shared object (dynamic library), while under Windows only ones specially marked as "exported" (which is different from "public") are visible after DLL is linked. So your complains go directly to the MS.